# What does "Hidden constructor called more than once per process" mean?

Tags: android

In my LogCat while debugging my app, I often get:

```
E/TelephonyManager(5382): Hidden constructor called more than once per process!
```

I've been Googling around a bit, and while I noticed other mentions of the error (in other logs), I cannot identify what it means.

So what is this error? Why am I getting it? And what is its significance?

Comment: check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375043/i-would-like-to-get-all-the-contact-listcontent-provider-and-append-them-into

Comment: @Phobos Can you explain the connection? Looks completely unrelated to me...

Comment: Without seeing your code I am assuming this is related to a cursor call, or format.  Check your contact contract, or whatever you are calling to make sure you are not creating 2 instances, and are using the correct call.

Comment: @Phobos Don't use cursors in this specific app.

Comment: Why does this message in logcat bother you? Does your application behave in any way unexpectedly?

Comment: @alex no my app is fine. But i simply want to know what it means. And if it has any connection to my app

Comment: @yydl But then you have no criteria of 'meaning' here. You can safely suppose it means nothing and is a noise, which it, most probably, is.

Comment: @Alex I suppose. But it must mean *something*. If I can find out its meaning, I can know what it definitively is. As opposed to just guessing.

Comment: @yydl Not necessarily. As if when you're programming and it's raining outside the rain does not mean anything in the context of your programming the same goes for this log message. You must excuse this my comment I'm taking evening courses in philosophy

Comment: You must be on a 4.0 device, correct? I'm getting this on the Galaxy Nexus but not other phones. I think Google limited access to the TelephonyManager in ICS.

Answer (score 0):

This is from the Android source code:

/**
 * Provides access to information about the telephony services on
 * the device. Applications can use the methods in this class to
 * determine telephony services and states, as well as to access some
 * types of subscriber information. Applications can also register
 * a listener to receive notification of telephony state changes.
 *

* You do not instantiate this class directly; instead, you retrieve
 * a reference to an instance through
 * {@link android.content.Context#getSystemService
 * Context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)}.
 *

* Note that access to some telephony information is
 * permission-protected. Your application cannot access the protected
 * information unless it has the appropriate permissions declared in
 * its manifest file. Where permissions apply, they are noted in the
 * the methods through which you access the protected information.
 */

```
public class TelephonyManager {

private static final String TAG = "TelephonyManager";

private static Context sContext;
private static ITelephonyRegistry sRegistry;

/** @hide */
public TelephonyManager(Context context) {
    context = context.getApplicationContext();
    if (sContext == null) {
        sContext = context;

        sRegistry = ITelephonyRegistry.Stub.asInterface(ServiceManager.getService(
                "telephony.registry"));
    } else if (sContext != context) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Hidden constructor called more than once per process!");
        Log.e(TAG, "Original: " + sContext.getPackageName() + ", new: " +
                context.getPackageName());
    }
}
```

The TelephonyManager seems to put the "Hidden constructor called more than once per process!" into the Log when your application calls the constructor more than once, as the message suggests. The constructor is called using the getSystemService as per the comments on the constructor.

Do you have more than one instance of:

```
telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
```

or something similar in your code? This could possibly be causing the error.

EDIT: If it's not your code causing the message then it's the program running with PID 5382 I think.