# Hidden constructor called more than once per process

Tags: android

I got this error in my logcat

```
TelephonyManager : Hidden constructor called more than once per process!
```

And my `PhoneListener` is not working

```
@Override
public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

                        switch (state) {
                        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                            Log.e("state", "idle");
                            break;
                        case TelephonyManager.DATA_CONNECTED:
                            Log.e("state", "connected");
                            break;
                        }
                    };
                };

    telManager = (TelephonyManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telManager.listen(callListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

It won't print out my log.

Answer (score 0):

From the source code i got this:

/**  Provides access to information about the telephony services on  the device. Applications can use the methods in this class to  determine telephony services and states, as well as to access some  types of subscriber information. Applications can also register  a listener to receive notification of telephony state changes.

You do not instantiate this class directly; instead, you retrieve  a reference to an instance through  {@link android.content.Context#getSystemService  Context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)}. *

Note that access to some telephony information is  permission-protected. Your application cannot access the protected * information unless it has the appropriate permissions declared in its manifest file. Where permissions apply, they are noted in the  the methods through which you access the protected information. **/

```
public class TelephonyManager {

private static final String TAG = "TelephonyManager";

private static Context sContext;
private static ITelephonyRegistry sRegistry;

/** @hide */
public TelephonyManager(Context context) {
    context = context.getApplicationContext();
    if (sContext == null) {
        sContext = context;

        sRegistry = ITelephonyRegistry.Stub.asInterface(ServiceManager.getService(
                "telephony.registry"));
    } else if (sContext != context) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Hidden constructor called more than once per process!");
        Log.e(TAG, "Original: " + sContext.getPackageName() + ", new: " +
                context.getPackageName());
    }
}
```

Are you creating multiple instance of TelephonyManger from different context? If so then the Error Log will show as the context is static.

Comment: At least cite where you got your answer dude. Here is the original source, http://stackoverflow.com/a/9335205